# Why did any slaves or former slaves choose to fight against Britain in the Revolutionary War?

Tags: united-states, britain, slavery, american-revolution

Considering the fact that they would have benefited more from a British victory, why would any slaves, current or former, choose to fight against the British?

Comment: @Semaphore  - They didn't have to.  The British offered to free them if they fought against the rebels.  Also, they knew that Americans were committed to slavery, so anyone other than Americans would have been more likely to have their best interests at heart.

Comment: Britain abolished slavery in the empire in 1833. What made you think slaves in 1765 could see into the future? At the time of the American rebellion, both sides promised freedom in exchange for service.

Comment: @Semaphore - point taken. Question edited.

Comment: Why would they have benefitted more from a British victory?

Comment: @Joe - the Americans enslaved them.  If I were in their shoes, I think I would prefer anything other than an American victory.  Also, the British offered to free any slaves who fought for them.  In the history of slavery, few nations have been as cruel and abusive to their slaves as Americans were.  The British were prone to abolitionist sentiment to a higher degree than Americans, and at an earlier date.  The founding fathers thought freedom only applied to white men who owned property (including other human beings).

Comment: The Native Americans knew which side their bread was buttered on.  For them and the slaves, life was unpleasant under the British, but intolerable under the Americans.

Comment: TL;DR - If the guys who whip and rape you get in a fight with guys who don't whip and rape you, you should root for the guys who don't whip and rape you.  There is at least a possibility that the whipping and raping will stop if they win.

Comment: The British were already the rulers when the terrible things were going on.  Why would a slave assume that keeping the same people in charge would make life better?

Comment: @Joe - The British were nominally in control, but in a very loose way.  The average slave would know very little about the British, and the people who tormented the average slave were all Americans.  The rebels still treated slaves like animals or farm tools, not people.  The British at least offered to free any slaves who fought for them.  The revolution didn't start because things had always been the same, it started because the British were finally tightening the reins.  From the slaves' POV, an American victory would have amounted to a continuation of the status quo.

Comment: A British victory would have represented more of a change, probably for the better, than an American victory.

Comment: And any slave who thought things would get worse if the Americans won would have been right- the number of slaves in the U.S. skyrocketed after the Revolution, and conditions for the slaves drastically deteriorated.

Comment: Native American tribes fought on both sides, for many reasons. Your view of historical action is very simplistic.  Even in the more cut and dried period of the US Civil War, the motivations of current slaves versus staying with their region or striking out for freedom were not as simple.  Individuals act, not groups.

Comment: @Oldcat - when you figure out how to condense complex issues into less than 600 characters without simplifying them, let me know.  Yes, Native Americans fought on both sides, but most supported the British, because they knew the British were more inclined to restrict westward migration.  Acting as individuals or small sects rather than a cohesive group is exactly what got the Native Americans wiped out.  Tecumseh was smart enough to realize that white people saw Indians as a single race, and that the Indians would be killed off unless they started thinking the same way.

Comment: @Oldcat I submit that Most of the time, people don't really act as individuals while committing atrocities, but as in-groups and out-groups - us and them.  That is certainly how white Americans treated everyone else.

Comment: When you start by denying humans their individuality, you quickly end up with useless nonsense.

Comment: I don't think I have done that.  I just believe that to commit atrocities, you need to submit your conscience to the dictates of a ruthless, collective, us and them mentality.  Hitler screaming gibberish venom on a street corner?  Basically harmless.  Hitler with millions of submissive stooges at his beck and call?  The worst part of the 20th century.

Comment: @Semaphore - the British abolished slavery in the Empire in 1833, but it was illegal in Britain long before that.  They were obviously more averse to slavery than Americans were.

Comment: @Wad Cheber - There were no "Americans": the British enslaved them. A British victory would imply "business as usual continues." A rebel victory implied a chance for change, and indeed several worked hard for emancipation, but the South said they wouldn't play on those terms.

Comment: @Zither13 - the British thought of Americans as subjects, not Britons.  A bit like the French view of French-Canadians, though the political context is very different.  In fact, the British tended to think "British" really meant "English", and the inhabitants of other parts of the Empire were supposed to be sources of profit, not citizens or participants in the life of the Empire.

Comment: Feel free to call me an idiot, not a subject I know much about, but didn't the Americans think arming their slaves a bit - err - dangerous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question - you have to dig past the superficial to understand, and I'm not fond of the way it is phrased, but the fundamental question is interesting.

[Here](http://boston1775.blogspot.com/2015/06/meeting-thomas-dugan-in-concord-7-june.html) is one example:

> Having fought as a teenager in the French and Indian War, Robbins served in an Acton militia company at the end of the siege of Boston. Caesar Robbins became free during the war. He raised his family in Concord, dying in 1822.

I don't know why Robbins chose to fight, I don't know why his owner chose to trust him with a weapon. (I'm making the broad assumption that "fought..." means that he was armed, although it is possible that he was merely part of the logistics train.)  I suspect that the author of the blog above would love to explore that issue.  In that sense I can't answer your question, but I can offer at least one example of why someone might want to.

Also note that the concept of slavery changes significantly around [Bacon's Rebellion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_Rebellion) and that the effects of Bacon's rebellion propagate more slowly in the Northeast where slavery is subject to different pressures than in the central states or the South. ([discussion of the evolution of slavery](http://thejuntocast.com/archives/ep-17-morgans-american-slavery-american-freedom/)).

Having offered my caveats, I *speculate* that some enslaved people (particularly in the Northeast) may have had more hope of fair treatment from their owners than from the institutions that their owners claimed were enslaving them.  Some may have perceived themselves as "Americans" (although enslaved, some of them had been here for generations and had no knowledge of other continents/countries/states).  Some may have had hope of emancipation & citizenship - remember the Marblehead brigade included free black men, so people in the Northeast would have had a model.

Some may have been promised freedom in exchange.

Comment: Brilliant answer!  I still think that the terror most white Americans felt at the prospect of arming black people - free or otherwise - should have been telling.  The British were willing to free slaves to win the war, but Jefferson described the owning of slaves as being like "having a wolf by the ears;  we cannot hold him for long, nor can we safely let him go".

Comment: most **Southern** white Americans....

Comment: There were plenty of slaves up north too, unfortunately, and most Americans, wherever they lived, were not comfortable with the idea of having people who had been wronged and might seek to avenge themselves living among them.   Even relatively progressive people were more inclined to send the slaves back to Africa than to let them live free in the U.S..

Comment: Hell, look at Lincoln- he is regarded as the great emancipator, but he himself said "If I could preserve the union by freeing all the slaves, I would.  If I could preserve the union by freeing none of the slaves, I would.  And if I could preserve the union by freeing some of the slaves but not others, I would do that."  The slaves were seen as a problem to be solved, not people who were entitled to freedom.

Comment: This statement is nonsense. Lincoln definitely saw slaves as humans, as did their owners.

Comment: I think that we're getting off topic and into discussion....

Comment: @Oldcat - slave owners saw slaves the way farmers see tractors, except farmers care about their tractors and don't beat them to a pulp when they break down, nor do they rape their tractors.  Mark - you're right.

Comment: @Oldcat - Lincoln clearly said that black people are inferior, which implies that, in his opinion, they were sub-human to some degree.  But if you want to defend slave owners, I won't stop you.  I'll just quietly judge you.  https://markii.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/racist-quote-by-abe-lincoln-happy-black-history-month/

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - I'm not happy with the phrasing either, but I'm not sure how to improve it.  Feel free to edit it as you see fit.  You clearly understand what I am trying to say, and I trust your judgement.

Comment: @Oldcat the very definition of slavery is 'people treated as property'.